# Installing PIP windows 10: connection broken

Tags: python, pip, installation, windows-10

I'm trying to install PIP on windows 10 following this
[link](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation)

saving the file get-pip.py to my disk and running it with CMD using

```
python get-pip.py
```

it get

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04F45170>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
```

I have admin rights and the antivirus is deactivated.

Where is the problem?

Comment: How have you installed `python`? `Pip` is most likely already included in your python installation. Note that the link you have posted is from an outdated project, which still relies on `python2`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set the pip proxy and add the following to pip.ini, which is located at Users\username\AppData\Roaming\pip, or you can create a new one. You may need to contact your network service department to get the proxy address.

```
[global]
proxy = [proxy address]:[proxy port]
```

Comment: where is pip.ini?
Where do I find the adress to connect to?

Comment: Still confused. 'Users\username\AppData\Roaming\pip' does not exist.
In ubuntu, Mint and even Win7 I did not need special adresses